# Understanding Multiple Context Bounds

Tags: scala

Looking at this [spire](https://github.com/typelevel/spire/blob/18f98314f3f4b9012d60c521414ced63699e2ba1/core/src/main/scala/spire/random/Dist.scala#L331) method's signature:

`implicit def complex[A: Fractional: Trig: IsReal: Dist]: Dist[Complex[A]]`

What is the meaning of `[A: Fractional: Trig ...]`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A context bound is a way of asserting the existence of an implicit value.  For example, the method signature:

```
def complex[A : Fractional]
```

Means that there must be a value of type `Fractional[A]` available in scope when the method is called (so that the method body can use `implicitly[Fractional[A]]` to get an instance of that type).  Compilation will fail if the compiler has no evidence of this fact.  Context bounds are really syntactic sugar, so that the above method signature is equivalent to:

```
def complex[A](implicit ev: Fractional[A])
```

Multiple context bounds simply mean that we are making multiple such assertions about the generic parameter:

```
def complex[A : Fractional : Trig]
```

Means that there must be a values of types `Fractional[A]` *and* `Trig[A]` in scope when the method is called.  So this method signature would be equivalent to:

```
def complex[A](implicit ev0: Fractional[A], ev1: Trig[A])
```

You can see this all in the REPL when you declare a method with the context bound syntax:

```
trait Foo[A]
trait Bar[A]
def foo[A : Foo : Bar] = ???
// foo: [A](implicit evidence$1: Foo[A], implicit evidence$2: Bar[A])Nothing
```

Comment: Actually it is not fully equivalent. When you have a nested class inside complex that is expecting a Manifest[A] and you make `def complex[A : Manifest]`, it will not supply the manifest, while if you do `complex[A](implicit mf: Manifest[A])` I find that it compiles well.