# Scala complex context bound

Tags: scala, type-bounds

In Scala 2.13 I would like pass a generic parameter of one type OR the another type:

```
def complex[A : Fractional | Trig]
```

Like Fractional OR Trig type.
Additional complexity is that the types haven't common parent.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731662/930014 sample with Fractional AND Trig types like:

```
def complex[A : Fractional : Trig]
```

But it doesn't suit me because it use **AND**.

How can I do it?

Comment: Which Scala version are you using?

Comment: Also, are you clear on the difference between a context bound and an [upper type bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html)?

Comment: You can't ask for `Or` implicits, unless you yourself encode a `Or` typeclass

Comment: Scala 2.13. I know about upper type bound. But the types haven't common parent.

Comment: It may be useful for futher discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/ew6epd/generics_with_multiple_different_bounds/

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Could you share a sample something `Or typeclass` like?

Comment: You may do something like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/eO5iHgUTRUWr2prpzX26NA Sadly, this doesn't ensure at last one of them to be available; that may be possible but would require more work - TBH, I would just either overload the method, or create my own typeclass that delegates to other instance; because using this `Or` is very complex.

Comment: @f4x There are implementations of `Or` in the question linked.